# How to Use MaterialAutoCompleteTextView with Completion Threshold

Tags: android, material-design, autocompletetextview, material-components-android

I'd like to start using material components in my Android app, and I am having a bit of trouble with the `MaterialAutoCompleteTextView`. I want it to behave like a standard AutoCompleteTextView, and I prefer the `OutlinedBox` style. Furthermore, it should observe the `completionThreshold` property, expanding the dropdown only after three matching characters are entered.

There are four styles available for this component that are creating an outlined box:
`Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu`
`Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu`
`Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense`
`Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox`

However, the first two styles do not observe the `completionThreshold` and expand the dropdown immediately when they are in focus. The remaining ones seem broken and are probably not meant to be used with this component.

One option obviously is to use one of the latter styles and modify it. But this could end up a bit messy for this relatively complex component, and it seems a rather hacky way to make use of a built-in behavior.

What would be the right approach?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:hint="Option 1"
        app:helperText="OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:completionThreshold="3"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:hint="Option 2"
        app:helperText="OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:completionThreshold="3"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:hint="Option 3"
        app:helperText="OutlinedBox.Dense"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:completionThreshold="3"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:hint="Option 4"
        app:helperText="OutlinedBox"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:completionThreshold="3"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try using `setThreshold(3)` on your `AutoCompleteTextView` in your java code, and also set `app:endIconMode="none"` in your xml, in the `TextInputLayout` that contains the `AutoCompleteTextView`.